# Добавление числа к числу

Tags: javascript

Как добавить к числу в `input`'е (поле для ввода) определенное число или процент за счёт кнопки `input`? Главное, чтобы он выводился в `h4` или `p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('inputId').value; // search input with id "inputId"
inputValue = parseInt(inputValue); // parse string value to integer
inputValue += 4; // or another number
document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML = inputValue; // search h4 tag and writing your value
```

Извини за коменты на английском, пытаюсь учить английский) Это был код на чистом js, а вот с использованием jQuery:

```
var inputValue = parseInt($('#inputId').prop('value')) + 4;
$('h4:eq(0)').html(inputValue);
```

Comment: пытаюсь учить английский - search *for* input

Comment: пытаюсь учить английский - похвально, но все же это stackoverflow **на русском**, поэтому желательно бы....